# Easy way to share profile configuration among profiles in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-profiles

I have a maven profile defined like so;

```
<profile>
            <id>instrumentation</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
                <property>
                    <name>instrumentation.enabled</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <formats>
                                <format>xml</format>
                                <format>html</format>
                            </formats>
                            <instrumentation>
                                <ignores>
                                </ignores>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>**/Test*.class</exclude>
                                    <exclude>**/Abstract*.java</exclude>
                                    <!-- Log Classes -->
                                    <exclude>**/Log.class</exclude>
                                    <!-- Exception Classes -->
                                    <exclude>**/*Exception.class</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </instrumentation>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>cobertura</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.6</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-resources</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                <!-- this is important -->
                                    <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                                    <!-- target -->
                                    <outputDirectory>${env.DERBASE}/java/${project.artifactId}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
                                    <resources>
                                        <resource>
                                        <!-- source -->
                                            <directory>${env.DERBASE}/java/${project.artifactId}/target/generated-classes/cobertura</directory>
                                        </resource>
                                    </resources>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

So what I would like to do is to change this line;

```
<goal>cobertura</goal>
```

to this;

```
<goal>instrumentation</goal>
```

If an env variable such as INSTRUMENTATION_EXCLUDE_TESTS is set.

I'm just wondering what the best way to accomplish this is? (i.e. without just copy and pasting the profile with the single line changed)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So, I solved this by setting an environment variable, which could be either;

```
export COBERTURA_GOAL=cobertura
```

or

```
export COBERTURA_GOAL=instrument
```

Then, in my pom, defined the following property;

```
<cobertura.goal>${env.COBERTURA_GOAL}</cobertura.goal>
```

Which was inserted into;

```
 <goal>${cobertura.goal}</goal>
```